# Case insensitivity in "if" statement (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working on a project that at one point will ask the user a yes/no question. I currently use this code to handle such questions:

```
def yn():
    global finalchoice
    choice=str(raw_input("Y/N: "))
    if choice == "Y":
        finalchoice="true"
    elif choice == "y":
        finalchoice="true"
    elif choice == "N":
        finalchoice="false"
    elif choice == "n":
        finalchoice="false"
    else:
        yn()
    pass
```

but this seems to be quite inefficient, specifically where I have to check for both "Y" and "y" or "N" and "n" separately. I've tried:

```
if choice == "Y" or "y":
    finalchoice="true"
```

Unfortunately, all this does is ignore the 'else' command and will pass whatever I give it.

Any tips?

Comment: You can convert you input into lower case so even if user inputs upper-case if will convert it into lower case and you can use 'y' or 'n' in your if case. 'choice=str.lower(raw_input("Y/N: "))'

Comment: @Aशwiniचhaudhary this question is definitely close, but Sudipta gave the answer I was really looking for.

Comment: @TanveerAlam also offered a great solution. Thanks to the both of you!

Comment: @Sil why use `"true"` and not `True`? Also, you could `return` instead of using `global`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe because I want to leave "finalchoice" as a string so that I can reuse it in the future. I don't want it to get set as a Boolean variable.

Comment: @Sil Kindly close the question by [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer if it worked for you.

Comment: @Sil that doesn't make sense, how is a Boolean *not* reusable? If you need a string representation later, `str(True).lower() == "true"`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I plan on using it for more than just "true" or "false" in the future is what I mean. If I try to assign a string to a Boolean, then I'll get an error.

Comment: @Sil what do you mean "assign a string to a Boolean"? Python is dynamically typed; if you later do `finalchoice = "foo"` that's fine, or you can use the existing value in the new string: `finalchoice = "value was {0}.".format(finalchoice)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`if choice == "Y" or "y":` is not right! It will always evaluate to `True`.

It essentially is `(choice == "Y")` or `("y")`. And the latter is `True` because any non empty string in python logically evaluates to boolean True.

You should be doing:

```
if choice in ["Y","y"]:
```

Or,

```
if choice == "Y" or choice == "y":
```

Or you can use:

```
if choice.lower() == "y":
    finalchoice="true"
```

Comment: choice.lower() is perfect solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

To add to @Sudipta's answer, one way would be to remove the case AND just take the first letter:

```
if choice.lower().startswith("y"):
    finalchoice="true"
```